# Ubuntu 14.04: '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found (SolusVM)

Tags: boot, partitioning, data-recovery, startup, grubrescue

Running Ubuntu 14.04, was doing some normal maintenance and updates last night, also added a VirtualHost.

The instance of Ubuntu is installed as a VPS in my SolusVMWare software. This means I cannot physically mount or plug anything into it so that another instance or startup of Linux could run.

I wondered why it wasn't connectable one day and realized in the VNC that it was stuck at a screen in start-up prompting the console for "grub rescue".. Is it possible for me to get all of my files back somehow and make a new VPS? Or is there a way to get the problem situated through grub rescue? Any ideas?

If it helps I get this..

```
Booting from Hard Disk...
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Please keep in mind I'm trying to keep what's on my Linux serer.